# Prevent import of android.R

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

How to prevent android.R package from autoimport in IntelliJ Idea?

It's really annoying when Idea import android.R package and you can't use R class from your project unless you delete "import android.R;" line in your code.

For example, I type this:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.sim
```

then press Ctrl+Space and select first item in completion. My code now look like this:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

and the imports now have

```
import android.R;
```

When I continue typing, and reach that moment:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                         getResources().getStringArray(R.array.
```

`R.array` is actually `android.R.array`, but that's not what I expect.

Comment: How restarting Eclipse can help with problems in IntelliJ Idea? :)

Comment: in my case, restarting Eclipse helped me severel times. Moreover you can unbind your Android library from eclipse. Then again bing it.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse. I use Intellij IDEA! That's completely different IDE.

Comment: Hmm so weird that so few people faced this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try these options:

[image: imports]

Disable **Add unambiguous imports on the fly** or add `android.R` to **Exclude from Import and Completion**.

Comment: Thanks! It's much better when android.R excluded. But this also disables code completion for android.R.* :(