# Intellij IDEA does not show class imports in autocomplete pop-up menu

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, autocomplete

Intellij IDEA does not show autocompletion for class imports. I know similar questions have been asked but I've searched both JetBrains and Stackoverflow and implemented all advised solutions but it still remains. I have to write imports manually. It happened unexpectedly when I simply restarted windows.
PS.: It also cannot resolve my view pages in Spring project.

[image: Screenshot2]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Make sure the import is [not excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623459/104891), also try File | Invalidate Caches.

Comment: Yes, I invalidated caches and it worked. Thanks, you save my day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can happen when the [import is excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623459/104891) or when the caches are corrupted.

Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Beware that invalidating caches in IntelliJ also wipes out your local history (the automatic built-in lightweight version control feature).