# Intellij auto complete just not working for java.util.HashMap

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2017.1.2 on MacOS High Sierra and the situation is when I type `OPTION+ENTER` it recommends me to import a class，Auto imports for all classes work well except for `HashMap`. For example, the class `HashTable` in the `java.util` package can auto complete.

I don't know what I had click or checked so how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623459/104891) help?

Answer (score 5):

See `Preferences > Editor > General > Auto Import > Exclude from Import and Completion`.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

With this exclusion in place IntelliJ will not offer `java.util.HashMap` as an auto import option.

If you remove this exclusion IntelliJ will resume offering `java.util.HashMap` as an auto import option.